# Sending second message after acknowledge of first one. Does RabbitMQ guarantee the order?

Tags: rabbitmq

Assume several producers publish to the same exchange E (fanout). Each producer has its own channel. Queue Q is bound to exchange E. producer P1 publishes message M1 to E and receives acknowledge A1 from E. Only after acknowledge A1 second producer P2 publishes second message M2. Does RabbitMQ guarantie order of messages in Q: M1 is first, M2 is second? That is will subscribed to Q consumer always receive M1 and after that M2?

Comment: Why do you have multiple producers when a producer (P2) is always waiting on the previous producer  (P1) to get ack? How do P1 and P2 communicate?

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ guarantees order of messages in a queue: First In, First Out. The first message to go into the queue will be the first message to come out of the queue, and they will remain in order (assuming you are just consuming and acking them... if you start nacking / rejecting message, re-publishing them, etc, things change)

That is the only guarantee that it will make on the order of messages: FIFO Queues.

If you need to guarantee the order that messages are delivered to a queue, you have to build that process yourself.

FWIW, it's very difficult to build this guarantee. The only truly guaranteed way to ensure the order of messages is not to send the next one until after the first one has been processed.

Even if you wait for the publisher acknowledgement before sending the next one, it is possible for the next one to end up in the queue before the first one (though it is highly unlikely).

You may want to look into [Message Sequence](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessageSequence.html) and [Resequencer](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Resequencer.html) if you need to guarantee the client gets messages in a certain order.

Comment: Thank you. I understand you answer as "No". We both agree that "The first message to go into the **queue** will be the first message to come out of the queue". But my question is about the **distance between exchange and queue**. And if I understand correctly you said that exchange can acknowledge obtaining of message M1 to P1, receive message M2 and put them in queue in reverse order: M2, then M1. Correct?

Comment: it is highly unlikely that this would happen, but still possible. M1 could be very large and require writing to disk, for example, while M2 is very small and does not require writing to disk. Or, the erlang process that is working on M1 could crash and have to restart, allowing M2 to get there first. Again, not likely scenarios, but possible, still.

Comment: ultimately, if you need guaranteed order of processing, you have use a sequencer and limit processing of a queue to 1 message at a time so you can properly re-sequence the messages if they are out of order

Comment: I referred to this answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53596761/regarding-message-order-guarantees-in-rabbitmq-amqp. I am not sure if this is correct, as RabbitMQ provides some basic order guarantees, which seem to be ignored here.