# Regarding message order guarantees in RabbitMQ/AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

One of the main characteristics of a message queue service, RabbitMQ included, is preserving message publication order. This is confirmed in the [RabbitMQ documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html#ordering):

> **[QUOTE 1]** Section 4.7 of the AMQP 0-9-1 core specification explains the
> conditions under which ordering is guaranteed: messages published in
> one channel, passing through one exchange and one queue and one
> outgoing channel will be received in the same order that they were
> sent. RabbitMQ offers stronger guarantees since release 2.7.0.

Let's assume in the following that there are no consumers active, to simplify things. We are publishing over one single channel.

So far, so good.

RabbitMQ also provides possibility to inform the publisher that a certain publication has been completely and correctly processed **[*]**. This is explained [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#publisher-confirms). Basically, the broker will either send a `basic.ack` or `basic.nack` message. The documentation also says this:

> **[QUOTE 2]** `basic.ack` for a persistent message routed to a durable queue will be
> sent after persisting the message to disk.
>
> In most cases, RabbitMQ will acknowledge messages to publishers in the
> same order they were published (this applies for messages published on
> a single channel). However, publisher acknowledgements are emitted
> asynchronously and can confirm a single message or a group of
> messages. The exact moment when a confirm is emitted depends on the
> delivery mode of a message (**persistent vs. transient**) and the
> properties of the queue(s) the message was routed to (see above).
> Which is to say that different messages can be considered ready for
> acknowledgement at different times. This means that acknowledgements
> can arrive in a different order compared to their respective messages.
> Applications should not depend on the order of acknowledgements when
> possible.

At first glance, this makes sense: persisting a message takes much more time than just storing it in memory, so it's perfectly possibly that the acknowledgment of a later transient message will arrive before the acknowledgement of an earlier persistent message.

But, if we re-read the first quote regarding message order **[QUOTE 1]**  here above, it gets confusing. I'll explain. Assume we are sending two messages to the same exchange: first a persistent and then a transient message. Since RabbitMQ claims to preserve message order, how can it send an acknowledgment of the second/transient message before it knows that the first/persistent message is indeed completely written to disk?

In other words, does the remark regarding illogical acknowledgement order **[QUOTE 2]**  here above only apply in case the two messages are each routed to completely different target queue(s) (which might happen if they have different routing keys, for example)? In that case, we don't have to guarantee anything as done in **[QUOTE 1]**.

**[*]** In most cases, this means 'queued'. However, if there are no routing rules applicable, it cannot be enqueued in a target queue. However, this is still a positive outcome regarding publication confirmation.

**update**

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35686609/8870331) on a similar question. This basically says that there are no guarantees whatsoever. Even the most naive implementation, where we delay the publication of message 2 to the point after we got an acknowledgment of message 1, might not result in the desired message order. Basically, **[QUOTE 1]** is not met.

Is this correct?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/YIeLCkLN6-4/BXnV_FXFBQAJ

Comment: I was about to refer to my post on the mailing list, thanks Luke. If Michael/you wants to provide an answer here on SO as well, feel free to do so. If not, I will somewhat copy/paste Michael's answer here (with a referral/credits to the list) later this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this response on `rabbitmq-users`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rabbitmq-users/YIeLCkLN6-4/BXnV_FXFBQAJ):

RabbitMQ knows message position in a queue regardless of whether it is transient or not.

My guess (I did not write that part of the docs) the ack ordering section primarily tries to communicate that if two messages are routed to two different queues, those queues will handle/replicate/persist them concurrently. Reasoning about ordering in *more than one* queue is pretty hard. A message can go into more than one queue as well.

Nonetheless, RabbitMQ queues know what position a message has in what queues. Once all routing/delivery acknowledgements are received by a channel that handled the publish, it is added to the list of acknowledgements to send out. Note that that
list may or may not be ordered the same way as the original publishes and worrying about that is not practical for many reasons, most importantly: the user typically primarily cares about the ordering in the queues.